# How to find a server with it's ID and then find its owner with discord.py

Tags: python, discord

The question says everything. I just want to get a server with a ID. something like this(just a example): `server=discord.guilds.get("server_id")` and then get it's owner's avatar image link and name. something like this `owner=server.owner.name`   /   `owner=server.owner.imageurl`.

Comment: You can do that just for the guilds the bot is in. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: @Dominik Yes, that’s what I want to do

Comment: Ok I got the answer